# dynamically creating td cell with paragraph in jquery

Tags: jquery-selectors

i am trying to create a table dynamically in such a way the generate code be like this:

```
        <table id="TblInvoiceList">

    <tr><td>name</td><td>amount</td></tr>
    <tr class="white"><td colspan="2"><p>bla bla<p></td></tr>

</table>
```

Here is my code:

```
createTable: function () {
    var lastRow = $('#TblInvoiceList tr:last');

    var newRow = $('<tr>');
    newRow.append($('<td>').text($('input.Name').val()), $('<td>').text($('input.GrossAmount').val()));
            lastRow.before(newRow);

    var hiddenRow = $('<tr>');
    hiddenRow.append($('<td colspan="3">'+ '<p>').text('bla bla'));
    newRow.after(hiddenRow);}
```

But de generated code doesnot have the

tag for the td cell with colspan.
How can i generate the following:

```
<td colspan='2'><p> bla bla </p><td>
```

Answer (score 0):

With .append() you can put html in directly, so you could do:

```
var someText = 'bla bla';
hiddenRow.append("<td colspan='2'><p>" + someText + "</p></td>");
```